# REST API responses as json

Tags: java, json, rest, api, objectmapper

I am writing a REST API that sends some data. I want this data to be in the format JSON.
I have this Object Mapper(seprate class):

```
public PSSMonitorJacksonJsonProvider() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = locateMapper(ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

    // our custom date/time format
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z"));

    // omit null values
    objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);

    objectMapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

    // ignore unknown properties
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
}
```

and this REST API:

```
@GET
@AnonymousAllowed
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getMessage() {
    return Response.ok(new ProjectResourceModel("Hell World", ""))
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, *")
            //.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "*")
            .build();
}

/**
 * Returns the number of all projects
 * from bitbucket
 *
 * @return number of projects in bitbucket
 */
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/number")
@AnonymousAllowed
public Response getNumberOfProjects() {

    return Response.ok((service.getNumberOfProjects()/*returns int*/))
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, *")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "*")
            .build();//gets the number of projects from the bitbucket api
}
```

As long as i return an object from a model then i works perfectly fine, but when i want to return a int directly it doesn't work. It returns it as a simple int. What do i have to do that my REST API returns/converts it as a json. I want to map all responses globally so i dont have to map each one on its own. Thanks

Comment: And what would be the correct JSON representation of a single int?

Comment: {1} for example. I need it in a json format so i can handle it correctly in the client. Or {value=1} but then i'd have to make a seperate model for int values, right? And i try to avoid that.

Comment: `{1}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: So what do you recommend i should do that it returns my int as a JSON that is a valid JSON? Do i need to make a model for that?

Comment: Easiest is to put your value in a map or a list and return that.

Comment: Okey then it returns a []. But this is kind of a workaround.

Comment: It's not a workaround. According to the spec, JSON text needs to be a serialized object or array. The easiest way to have Jackson output an object is by returning a map, the easiest way to have it output an array is by returning a list.